# Read latest SPSS file from directory

Tags: r, dataframe, spss

I am trying to read the latest SPSS file from the directory which has several SPSS files. I want to read only the newest file from a list of 3 files which changes with time. Currently, I have manually entered the filename (SPSS-1568207835.sav for ex.) which works absolutely fine, but I want to make this dynamic and automatically fetch the latest file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
     setwd('/file/path/for/this/file/SPSS')

     library(expss)

      expss_output_viewer()

       mydata = read_spss("SPSS-1568207835.sav",reencode = TRUE)
        w <- data.frame(mydata)
        args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return a character string for the filename of the .sav file modified most recently

```
# get all .sav files
all_sav <- list.files(pattern ='\\.sav$')
# use file.info to get the index of the file most recently modified
all_sav[with(file.info(all_sav), which.max(mtime))]
```

Comment: This works perfectly but its taking too much time to get the data from the file. Is there a way we can make it time-efficient? For the first time, it's taking too much time to create the data table from the last modified file. Do we have an alternative for this which takes fairly less time to load.

Comment: The file sizes are quite larger like 112MB or more. I have been looking for answers here and there but couldn't find anything useful for expss package.